# swift create wizard with page view controller

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to create a question wizard, where the user must answer some questions... The thing is, I want to group them on three pages (put some form fields on each) and let him walk throuh it. At the end, when all data is filled in, I want to send it to REST Api.

I have everything set up and working, but I dont know how to implement the wizard.
After playing around with the page view controller, I thought maybe I can use it for that. But honestly, i followed a tutorial where one view controller with an image view is loaded and the images come from an array holding the images...

Thats easy, because placing the image view via storyboard is easy and the constraints are easy to handle..

But how can I place different Labels and TextFields?
Do I have to put them all in the view controller or can I use different view controllers that are loaded from the the page view controller?

THX for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of a few ways

- Create separate view controllers with the labels and text fields explicitly placed in Interface Builder for all questions as you've mentioned. This will likely introduce a lot of duplication if the questions have similar potential responses.
- Create a set of view controllers that represent all possible layouts and choose the one you need dynamically based on the content (e.g. question type). For example if it's a 4 choice or 3 choice multiple choice question, or an open ended question with a text field or text view for the answer, etc. These could then be reused depending on how your question data is defined.
- Create a way to dynamically specify all of the layout variables--perhaps a JSON document--where you can add everything dynamically in code including control positioning. Though a convention is probably easier to implementing then full-explicit placement in code.

If it were me, I would probably go with the second one of those two and develop a meta data question/answer description in a JSON document. Something like this might get you started:

```
{
  "questions" : [
    {
      "question" : "What was your favorite part of the course?",
      "type" : "multi",
      "options" : [
        "Introduction",
        "Content",
        "Conclusion"
      ]
    },
    {
      "question" : "How would you improve the course if you could?",
      "type" : "open-ended",
      "options" : []
    },
    {
      "question" : "Did your lab partner provide adequate input?",
      "type" : "bool",
      "options" : [
        "Yes",
        "No"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You can analyze the question type field and determine from that which view controller to use. If you have a multiple choice, for example, you could have it contain a table view that would load all of the options and would allow the user to tap the table cells containing the options and toggling a checkbox in the cell accessory.

For an open ended question, just ignore the "options" array. In your view controller for that type of question, just show the question in a label and then a text field for the answer.

Or for a question of bool type, you could have default options of yes/no, but allow the options to be something else like true/false as well. The control you would use in that view controller would be a UISwitch.

Anyhow, the options are pretty open since you're defining it, but I would definitely try to find a nice balance between keeping it dynamic with your own meta data DSL, but not making so much work for yourself it's not worth it. I chose JSON because that's something you could either bundle in your app and just load from disk or you could just as easily download it from an endpoint if you wanted it to be something that could be updated on a regular basis without having to re-build your app.